# grep -r not available; what now?

Tags: shell, text, command-line, grep

I am trying to search recursively for a string in all files contained in the current folder, where I am executing grep. But it seems that `grep` on this host is too old. Here are some usages of it.

```
>> grep -r "some string here" *.*
grep: illegal option -- r
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]
```

So how should I do what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have `find`,

```
find . -type f -exec grep "some string here" {} \;
```

Notice also that your wildcard would only match files whose name contained a dot; I assume that was a mistake, but if not, add `-name '*.*'` before `-exec` (or change the `find .` to `find *.*` if you meant to search directories whose name contains a dot, which is what your `grep` command would actually do).

The old DOS 8+3 wildcard `*.*` would match all files because the dot was implicit even in file names which didn't have an extension. The Unix wildcard for all files (which do not start with a dot) is simply `*`.

This could be made a bit more efficient with `xargs` or with a newer `find` which supports `-exec ... +`

Comment: Or make it `find . -type f -exec grep "some string here" {} /dev/null \;` if you want the matches to be preceded by the matching file name.

Comment: The screen just flashes and I can't see the results listing me the file names.
So far I managed to use the following statement:

grep -F Ma /Dir/* 

Searching for the string "Ma" into the desired Dir.

Comment: Found this fancy thing ;D  
[www.computerhope.com](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm)

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров: I think you meant: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm (no ssl).

Comment: Not sure what the link is supposed to demonstrate. I get an SSL error and a 404.

Comment: Pipe the output to `less` if it goes too fast, or redirect it to a file.

Comment: @Thor yep, that's the one

Comment: @tripleee This is out of option the server is a client's !

Comment: Not sure what that means. You can't use `find` because the client won't let you?

Comment: The link looks like a paraphrase of the manual page for GNU `grep`.

Comment: @tripleee I cannot redirect it to a file, because my session is a Read only and I'm not allowed to write on the clients' machine.

Comment: Not eve `/tmp`? Then pipe to `less` as already suggested, or run the command over `ssh` from a host where you do have write access.

Comment: @tripleee If I was able to do this it would have done this thing already ;D. You see I am connecting to a machine, then from it I am connecting to another one via Putty/SSH only with reading right everywhere... not just a remote machine, but rather the remote of the remote.

Comment: I am also trying to read the contents of a *.Z files and searching for a string located in those and I want to output:<br>

<ol>1. The name of the file that it found it in</ol>
<ol>2. The line # where it found it</ol>
<ol>3. [Optional] Print the line contents.</ol>

Comment: So far I got this: find . -name "*.Z" | xargs zcat | grep -n "string_to_search for". But it still does not print what I want.. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Multi-hop SSH doesn't really change the picture. `ssh gateway ssh destination find ... >/tmp/file`. But again, a pipeline to `less` will not require write access anywhere.

Comment: `find . -name '*.Z' | xargs zgrep -n "string to search for"` should do what you want. But if you have a different question, post a new one rather than heaping new requirements in comments to this one.